# unable to post values of multiple check boxes created form while loop

Tags: php, html

My question maybe has been asked many times before but i couldn't apply the given solutions on my project yet

I'm trying to post only the selected children check-boxes not the parents

my page code is:

```
     <?php  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123', 'test'); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="cbFamily.js"></script>
     </head>

    <body>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="test.php">
     <section class="demo2" style="margin-top:2px;">

     <?php
     $query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tblmainjobs");

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):
     ?>
    <section>
    <h3><label><input type="checkbox" /> <?php echo $row["mainjob"]; ?> 
    </label></h3>

    <?php 
    $query2=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT userjob FROM users WHERE 
    '".$row["mainjob"]."' = users.mainjob GROUP BY users.userjob");
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)):
    ?>
    <div class="children">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo 
    $row2["userjob"]; ?>"/> <?php echo $row2["userjob"]; ?></label>       

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </section>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">  <!-- this function for selecting all 
    children checkboxes once the parents checkbox bieng selected -->
    $("h3 input:checkbox").cbFamily(function (){
    return $(this).parents("h3").next().find("input:checkbox");
    });
    </script>

    </section>  

    <br>
    <div><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

my page looks like this
[test.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grlrl.png)

my entire project is attached here 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/6ikcaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo 
$row2["userjob"]; ?>"/> <?php echo $row2["userjob"]; ?>
```

notice the [] in the name attribute.

Comment: I did it but get no results

Comment: Does it also comes empty if you manually check the child checkboxes? can you var_dump($_POST) and paste the output here?

Comment: yes Mr.ACD nothing is happened BTW, my project is attached, could u plz take a look on it

Comment: I can definitely see output using: <?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

Also, you don't have to put name and value for your submit. just type attribute will do. Here's an updated copy of your project: https://ufile.io/rqapc

Comment: I tried <?php echo json_encode($_POST['checkbox']); ?> and got all the results but when i receive it by $names = $_POST['checkbox'];  in another page i got nothing

Comment: how do you mean another page? can you send your code with the "another page".

Comment: I mean the main page which has the database connection parameters and other functions like  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  update();
 }                          function update(){
  global $db, $errors;                           $upload_date = $_POST['upload_date'];
  $names = $_POST['checkbox'];

Comment: the main idea is to assign $_POST['checkbox'] to the $names then do update query like this $query = "INSERT INTO files(names, ishariNo) VALUES ('$names', '$ishariNo')";

Comment: Just throwing out hunches here. can you add novalidate attribute to your form.

Comment: Just add novalidate in the form attribute: `<form name="myform" method="post" action="test.php" novalidate>`

Comment: I did it and i also added this $names = json_encode($_POST['checkbox'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); to received the posted values from another page .. now i got the results like this ["editor","director"] but i need them like this editor, director, .. etc what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to disable the "parent" checkboxes before they get posted to the server.

Add a class to your parent checkboxes to make for an easy jquery selector:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="parent" />
```

Then some javascript to disable the checkboxes:

```
$(".parent").prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: thank u Mr.eaburk for ur response but what should i do with this $(".parent").prop("disabled",true); ?

Comment: You could put this in a click event for the submit button.

Comment: i did like this        <div><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="doStart();"/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function doStart(){
$(".parent").prop("disabled",true);
}
</script>            is it true?

Comment: Normally I would put it up in a script tag in the head section. <head><script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){ $(".submit").click(function(){ $(".parent").prop("disabled",true); } }); </script></head>